# got Exception in Tkinter callback when do getter setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so, I want to pass a value between two classes with sparated file by creating a new class as connector between them (getter and setter)

so, there're all of my code:

UIinput.py

```
from tkinter import *
from getset import getset
from restRFID import restRFID

class UIinput:

    varInput = ""
    varIN = ""
    sset = getset()
    def inputDat():
        global varIN
        ui = Tk()
        ui.geometry("300x300")
        ui.title("Input Data")
        frame1 = Frame(ui)
        frame1.pack()

        frame2 = Frame(ui)
        frame2.pack()

        label1 = Label(frame1, text = "Masukkan nama: ")
        label1.pack(side = LEFT)

        textbox1 = Entry(frame1, bd = 5, width = 20)
        textbox1.pack(side = LEFT)


        varIN = textbox1.get() 

        Button1 = Button(ui, text = "Input", command = lambda: UIinput.process(textbox1.get()))
        Button1.place(x = 150,y = 50)
        ui.mainloop()
    def process(dat):
        UIinput.sset.set(str(dat))
        restRFID.getDat()

UIinput.inputDat()
```

restRFID.py

```
from tkinter import *
from getset import getset
class restRFID:
      getdat = getset()
      def getDat():

          ui = Tk()
          ui.geometry("300x300")
          frame1 = Frame(ui)
          ui.title("Get Data")
          frame1.pack()

          frame2 = Frame(ui)
          frame2.pack()

          dat = StringVar()

          dat.set(str(restRFID.getdat.get()))
          label1 = Label(frame1, textvariable = dat)
          label1.pack(side = LEFT)
          ui.mainloop()
```

and the last is my code that I use as a setter getter for all the code above this code

getset.py

```
class getset(object):

def set(self, x):
    self.inputdata = x

def get(self):
    return self.inputdata
```

but when I try to compile it I got an error exception:

```
AttributeError: 'getset' object has no attribute 'inputdata'
```

but if try implemnt the getter and setter method in getset.py class, it's run succesfully without any errors.

Comment: Maybe it wants to get the data to display it first. You probably need to initialise the member data. In fact: `restRFID.getdat.get()` happens before `set` is called. In fact `set` is never called.

Comment: I already do `set` by run UIinput.py firstly by process it when UIinput.py already get a value from the entry and click a button ( it prossesed in `UIinput.process(textbox1.get())`)

Comment: But you have two different instances of `getset` one that you call `get` on the other you call `set`.

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the `set()` method has been called before the `set()` method?